# How to enter passkey for encrypted communications through Objective-C's CoreBluetooth on OSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-bluetooth

I am working on an Objective-C Bluetooth library for use with Unity3D on iOS and macOS. When attempting to access an encryption-only characteristic on iOS I am presented with the passkey entry modal and an bond is established. 
However, on macOS, I am not shown this and I am unsure how to trigger the bonding process.

Comment: Hi @Ihaugh, this is a good question!  Can you share some minimal code so we can quickly reproduce the situation?  Maybe some code that triggers the passkey entry model on iOS but not on macOS?